# How to draw multiple Imageview on Canvas with clicklistener

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw multiple Imageview on Canvas with clicklistener and set image view position using coordinate.
When I clicked on Imageview it's get image from folder and set.

Answer (score 0):

get the uri of image,Set Imagematrix to imageview for set image at specific co-ordinates,For draw on canvas get drawable from imageview and draw it on canvas.
Alternate solution for get image from all imageview is set all imageview  under one parent view and get the drawable from parent view.